# CKEditor Internal links are not prefixed with language

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n, wysiwyg

I have a multilingual Drupal site and I noticed that the paths of relative links added by CKEditor ignore the current language prefix and redirect to that node pages with default language (ie. /cn/home -> /introduction). I have tried using **Linkit** Module but the issues still exists. My Drupal version is 8.4.7.

Any possible solution for this problem?

Comment: see this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit/issues/2280441 also this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit/issues/2692831 seems its fixed in the dev version

Comment: @Ziftman I found the reason of my problem - it is because I link to some Views Pages that cannot be detected by the Linkit. **Linkit views** seems to be the solution but it is not available for Drupal 8...